# Controller stops updating value after the value is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use angular to change the css class of an element when a user inputs data, both after a button click and in real time as the user is typing in data.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="defaultClass" ng-class="{true: 'errorClass',
false:'defaultClass'}[updateInput()]" ng-model="inputOne">
```

CSS:

```
.defaultClass {border: 1px solid #ccc;}

.errorClass {border: 1px solid #FF0000;}
```

After a button is pressed, the controller checks if the model of the element is blank and if so, makes the function return true and therefore changes the css class in the ng-class to show an error.

```
$scope.calcButton = function (){

if ($scope.inputOne === "" || $scope.inputOne === undefined) {
    $scope.updateInput = function() {
        return true;
    };
} else {
    $scope.updateInput = function() {
        return false;
    };
}

};
```

Outside of the button click function, I have the following code in the same controller that *should be* watching the status of $scope.inputOne and returning true or false based upon the status of the input:

```
$scope.updateInput = function() {
    if ($scope.inputOne === "") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 };
```

And it works fine as long as I don't click the button, but once the value is changed by the button press the controller stops checking if the input field is empty or filled.

This is a problem because I want to have the error messages fade away as the user types in data after a button press that threw errors, but I can't change the css by user input at this point.

Why does it do this? How can I ensure that the controller still keeps track of what's going on in the input field after the button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
ng-class="{'errorClass' : !inputOne,'defaultClass': inputOne }"
```

or like this

```
ng-class="!inputOne ? 'errorClass' : 'defaultClass'"
```

`'',null,NaN,undefined,0` etc considered `false` in JavaScript.

just check model has value or not.

It'll work through two way binding . don't need method for this to check

Comment: It works but also creates another problem because the error is shown on default. The reason I had it in a method before was because I only wanted it to start checking for errors after a change had already occurred.

Comment: @Tater Then use `ng-class="{'errorClass' : inputOne=='' ,'defaultClass': inputOne }" `